# Clickatell sending blank message to iphone from sandbox account

Tags: clickatell

I'm using clickatell sandbox account, when i try to send sms to iphone using [send sms api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api) receiving only blank message.

PS: In Andriod it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Since no adjustments are required between iOS and Android, and the Android device received your message, the problem is likely with the handset.

Suggestions:

- Ensure that network coverage is strong
- Ensure that the mobile number(s) is not in roaming mode
- Ensure that phone memory capacity is not full
- Restart the iPhone to refresh the device on the network (keep the device off for +-10mins)
- Check if any phone applications or settings may filter out messages, or consider swapping the sim to another phone to test
- After checking all of these, you can try again

Should you still have an issue, I recommend contacting Clickatell support on support@clickatell.com. They would be able to run live coverage tests for you.